# Validate element in http handlers

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

In ASP.NET, http handlers can contain a validate element.

What exactly does this do/mean?

Comment: for some reason my answer got downvoted, but it's the only one at present and I *believe* that it's correct, is there some information it's missing for you to have taken it as an accepted answer? =)

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN [HttpHandlerAction.Validate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httphandleraction.validate.aspx):

> If the Validate property is false,
>   ASP.NET will not attempt to load the
>   class until the actual matching
>   request comes, potentially delaying
>   the error but improving the startup
>   time.